# UUID of bluetooth server and client

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

what is UUID in android `bluetoothserversocket` meant? how we can set UUID for bluetooth server and client?

Comment: UUID is a universal unique identifier, it is meant to be a unique identifier and it is designed to be unique in most cases.  It is generated at random, there isn't anything more about it really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long story but let's short it.
Yes, UUID is an universal unique identifier to mark one special items, e.g. profiles, or characters, or whatever, just like your driver license's ID.
On Bluetooth, SIG defined some official UUID and you can find here: 
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery

Then regarding to the `bluetoothserversocket`, this is the SPP actually and SPP does have the UUID named `0x1101`. however more and more requests need that more SPP channel on one device, hence more and more Bluetooth stack vendor defined the multi-SPP support channel, but the official UUID only one, so we can define our spec UUID, which need client and server use the same UUID.

The value itself can be defined any value only if it is "universal unique".